# python dictionary look for value returns wrong result

Tags: python, dictionary

```
#yearly_weather
import os
from datetime import datetime, date
import datetime
test={datetime.date(1977, 6, 5): [81, 55, 0.0, False],
 datetime.date(2007, 11, 18): [45, 41, 0.02, True],
 datetime.date(2017, 11, 3): [43, 33, 0.3, True],
 datetime.date(2007, 2, 24): [44, 36, 0.36, True],
 datetime.date(2015, 2, 18): [54, 40, 0.0, False],
 datetime.date(2008, 11, 18): [51, 43, 0.01, True],
 datetime.date(1965, 12, 29): [43, 33, 0.27, True]}


#yearly_weather={year:[AVG_TMAX, AVG_TMIN, TOTAL_PRCP, TOTAL_RAINY_DAYS, TOTAL_DAYS]}  
# datetime.date(1965, 12, 29): [43, 33, 0.27, True]}
#{2017: [45.666666666666664, 34.333333333333336, 2.28, 9, 15]}
temp={}
yearly_weather={}
for k,v in test.items():
    year=k.year
    value=temp.get(k.year,(0,0,0,0,0,0))
    sumtmax=v[0]+value[0]
    counttmax=value[1]+1
    sumtmin=v[1]+value[2]
    counttmin=value[3]+1
    sumprcp=v[2]+value[4]
    sumrainy=v[3]+value[5]
    sumdays=counttmax
    temp[k.year]=(sumtmax,counttmax,sumtmin,counttmin,sumprcp,sumrainy,sumdays)
    #print(temp)
for k,v in temp.items():
    yearly_weather[k]=(v[0]/v[1],v[2]/v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6])

print(yearly_weather)

def year_info(year, yearly_weather):
    for k,v in yearly_weather.items():
        if year==k:
            return "{:<8.0f}| {:<18.2f}| {:>12.2f} | {:>10.2f} | {:>10.0f}| {:>10.0f}" .format(k,v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4])

        else:
            return "{:^8s}| {:^18s}| {:^12s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s}".format("N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A")


year="1965"
year=int(year)
year_info(year,yearly_weather)
```

---

```
  N/A   |        N/A        |     N/A      |    N/A     |    N/A     |    N/A
```

when I try to look for a specific year's info, 
its supposed to return weather information, why it turns N/A?

ignore: repeat question for word requirements
ignore: repeat question for word requirements

Comment: "why it turns N/A?"  Because you iterate over .  If the first year iterated over doesn't match the test in if-statement, the else-clause fires and returns `N/A`.  So this method will only succeed when you try to fetch the first year in the iteration order of `yearly_weather.items()`.  For your approach to work you need get rid of the else-clause and move the `return N/A` outside of the loop.  But that's the wrong way to do it.  See @jpp's answer for the right way.

Comment: yes I now understand his code is more efficient, thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to iterate your dictionary. Just access the appropriate dictionary item directly. If you need to deal with `KeyError`, you can use a `try` / `except` clause:

```
def year_info(year, yearly_weather):
    try:
        k = year
        v = yearly_weather[k]
        return "{:<8.0f}| {:<18.2f}| {:>12.2f} | {:>10.2f} | {:>10.0f}| {:>10.0f}" .format(k, *v)
    except KeyError:
        return "{:^8s}| {:^18s}| {:^12s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s}".format(*['N/A']*6)
```

**Result**

```
res = year_info(1965, yearly_weather)

'1965    | 43.00             |        33.00 |       0.27 |          1|          1'
```

Comment: It would be tempting get rid of the temporary variables `.format(year, *yearly_weather[year])`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, Yep, good point, I'll still keep the `k` and `v` though, if only to limit that line length. Also changed to `.format(*['N/A']*6)`

Answer (score 1):

First year is 1977, it is different from 1965, so the function **returns** "N/A". It doesn't check the next item in the set.

Try this code instead:

```
def year_info(year, yearly_weather):
    for k,v in yearly_weather.items():
        if year==k:
            return "{:<8.0f}| {:<18.2f}| {:>12.2f} | {:>10.2f} | {:>10.0f}| {:>10.0f}" .format(k,v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4])

    return "{:^8s}| {:^18s}| {:^12s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s} | {:^10s}".format("N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A","N/A")
```

Comment: Only issue with this is O(*n*) time complexity versus what should be O(1).

Comment: ah I understand what you mean now, this way it takes longer to get the result

Comment: @jpp of course you are right. I tried to answer OP's question "why it [re]turns N/A"; you showed how to use dict as intended, but without indicating *why* it returned N/A in his original code.